# Error creating folder with OneDrive API - Javascript

Tags: javascript, post, ionic2, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I'm having issues creating a folder via the onedrive api. I am able to get at my main drive, access files, and get file information. When I try to create a folder, I am getting an error. I am developing this with Anuglar on top of Ionic. There error I am receiving is

```
"error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "Entity only allows writes with a JSON Content-Type header.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "5773433a-bf81-4226-bdc0-12beda3e6b03",
      "date": "2017-06-05T23:49:57"
    }
  }
```

I am have the correct token (I am using this in other functions and if I do not include the token in the header, I get a different error). Here is the code that is being called.

```
public createFolder(token) {
    this.http.post('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/children', {"name": "FolderA", "folder": {"childCount": 0}}, {"Authorization": "Bearer " + token, "Content-Type": "application/json"})
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error.status);
        console.log(error.error);
        console.log(error.headers);
      })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post) Config should have headers under "headers" key:

```
{"headers": {"Authorization": "Bearer " + token, "Content-Type": "application/json"}}
```